# How to include and exclude scenarios from test execution in JBehave?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, jbehave, thucydides

I have some stories. Every story has some scenarios.
Example:

```
Story 1.
Scenario 1.
Scenario 2.
Scenario 3.
Story 2.
Scenario 1.
Scenario 2.
```

TestNG has suite.xml file for configuration which test and\or methods should be executed.

I found in jBehave StoryFinder class, but it needs to modify my code every time when I execute different scenarios.

I want to execute, for example, in Story 1 Scenario 2 and Scenario 3 and in Story 2 only Scenario 2. 
I did not found how I make to configure jBehave stories for easily configuration.

Comment: Could you please help me that how to integrate testNG in Jbehave. I just need sample code only for test runner class file using testNG which will run test steps class file. Please share some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using meta tag, @skip in scenarios.

Example given here: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-info.html

Comment: It's not good if you have about 1000 scenario, and you want to execute  parallel two different suite.

Comment: I agree with you. One story for one scenario - is the rigth way